# VS Code: state-based block comment/uncomment

Tags: visual-studio-code

A feature I have used a lot in Geany is the 'state-based' block comment/uncomment, where commented lines in the selected block are switched to uncommented, and uncommented ones are switched to commented. Geany uses a modified comment code '#~ ' (in python) so it can keep track of lines commented out by the editor, as opposed to genuine comments in the code.

```
x = 1
#~ x = 2
y = 3
#~ y = 4
```

In geany, highlighting the whole block and pressing Ctrl-e gives

```
#~ x = 1
x = 2
#~ y = 3
y = 4
```

Is there any way to get similar behaviour in VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules)

Add this to your `settings.json`

```json
  "replacerules.rules": {
    "Toggle Comment #~": {
      "find": ["^([ \\t]*)#~ (.*)$", "^([ \\t]*)(?=[^ \\t])(?!#@# )(.*)$", "^([ \\t]*)#@# (.*)$"],
      "replace": ["$1#@# $2", "$1#~ $2", "$1$2"]
    }
  }
```

Because the find replaces are done sequential you have to mark the lines with a state comment (`#~` ) to delete the comment in step 3.

Step 2 emulates a Greedy-Non-Backtrack `*` for whitespace

For other comment styles you have to duplicate this rule.

You can add this to a keybinding:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "replacerules.runRule",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly",
    "args": {
        "ruleName": "Toggle Comment #~"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an extension I made: [Toggle Line Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.toggle-comments).  I can't test it on Geany though.

[image: toggling on/off line comments]

Comment: Unfortunately this extension also uncomments lines which are genuine comments and need to be preserved as such.